# QT5 Unicode argument works in IDE but not in final exe?

Tags: windows, unicode, qt5, argv, qt5.4

When I pass the same unicode argument from `QT5->Projects->Run` the app works, but fails if passed as an argument directly to the exe. The arguments are being passed from an webpage encoded using `encodeURIComponent` in javascript.

**The code is:**

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);


        if(a.arguments().count() < 2)
        {
            qFatal("No argument provided");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        QStringList args = a.arguments().at(1).split("####");

        QString param1 = args.at(1);
        QUrl downurl = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(param.toLocal8Bit());
..........
    }
```

Comment: In what way “fails”? Are you saying percent-encoded UTF8 sequences are misdecoded on input? Are you saying that raw non-ASCII characters are being misdecoded? The latter in an unavoidable  limitation of the Windows console.

Comment: The app crashes with following information by windows - https://dpaste.de/dyh2

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, using `param.toUtf8()` in the above code fixes this.